# How To Get Background Worker To Report Progress Over WCF (Winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

In my winform program, I have a method that calls on a DLL which in turn calls either a WCF service to synchronize data with QuickBooks remotely or it does the work of the service itself locally.

The code inside my program looks like this:

```
        public void SyncAccounts(BackgroundWorker currentThread)
    {

        AccountingOpsManagerClass managerClass = new AccountingOpsManagerClass();
        managerClass.CreateOpsConnection(connectionDTO, checkEditUseWCF.Checked);
        managerClass.SyncAccounts(currentThread, connectionDTO, interfaceDTO);

    }
```

There are other methods as well for progress changed and do work.

The code inside of the DLL that determines to use the service or a local QB looks like this:

```
        public void SyncAccounts ( BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker, AccountingOpConnectionDTO connectionDTO, InterfaceDTO interfaceDTO)
    {
        if (useWCF == true)
        {
            WCFClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            WCFClient.CreateConnection(opsConnectionDTO);
            WCFClient.SyncAccounts(backgroundWorker, connectionDTO, interfaceDTO);
            try
            {
                ((IClientChannel)WCFClient).Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                ((IClientChannel)WCFClient).Abort();
            }
        }

        else

        {
            SyncAccountsCommand command = new SyncAccountsCommand(backgroundWorker);
            command.Sync(connectionDTO, interfaceDTO);
        }
    }
```

And then the code inside of the service looks like this:

```
    public void SyncAccounts(BackgroundWorker currentThread, AccountingOpConnectionDTO connectionDTO, InterfaceDTO interfaceDTO)
    {
        SyncAccountsCommand command = new SyncAccountsCommand(currentThread);
        command.Sync(connectionDTO, interfaceDTO);
    }
```

When I perform a local synchronization with QB, the report progress method inside of my program fires and I get back the status (I.E. logging info, progress percentage, etc.) However when I do a synchronization using the service, the progress changed event never fires. The interesting thing is that in both scenarios, the background worker does report back the is busy value as true during the sync. Its just the progress changed method that does not seem to be working during the sync.

Could someone with more experience with WCF please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Although your backgroundworker did get instantiated in the WCF service, it is a different instance, in a different process. Delegates don't get re-wired. You can't callback into the caller from the service. Best is to fake its progress with a timer or so.

Comment: I had a feeling that was probably the case with this problem. I ended up resorting to having the service return a response object when it is done processing and in the mean time the client has a wait form that appears while it's waiting for the service to respond. Not exactly the most desirable solution, but our use case allows for such, so I've moved onto other things within the application.